# Likes & comment notifications w/ Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, notifications, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have a fully functioning application, similar to Instagram where a user can like and comment on another users post. I was wondering, what is the best way to go about creating some kind of notification system in Swift, using Firebase that can observe who liked a post, what post they liked and notify with an actual notification. If this is not possible via Firebase, what is the best way to go about this? Any help will be hight appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This might help you out. https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/ios/console-device however I've seen in other places that firebase is not good for push notifications so you might need to use a third party for it.

Comment: Read more into Firebase Cloud Messaging. You'll basically need a server to *listen* to the changes in your database and push the notifications accordingly. You can't send push notifications using a device-to-device system unfortunately.